# How to avoid global state in PHP MVP architecture

Tags: php, global-variables, mvp

I need some help in understanding dependency injection. I am trying to avoid using global state (objects, properties, etc.) and trying to implement dependency injection. My issue in particular is the following: let's suppose that I am getting the request from the uri, and knowing that, I call the presenter and the method. I cannot understand how am I going to send to a particular presenter ONLY the things it needs, when I actually don't know what it needs at the time I process the uri request. I might be confused and misunderstood the things, and that's the reason I am writing here.

If I use a registry then I would have all of the objects stored in it available to use, but that's what we are trying to avoid, right? On the other hand, if I use a dependency injection I will need to send the objects I need through the constructor or through mutator methods, but as I already said I don't know what the presenter is going to need at the time of processing the request. Is it really possible to get this done without using some kind of global?

I would appreciate if someone can explain to me on how to deal with this issue, or maybe point me some resources where I can understand it better.

Comment: Not an expert here, but [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) uses DI throughout. You could do much worse than downloading a copy and running through their tutorials.

Comment: Do a Google search for `dependency injection demystified`, if you haven't already. The practicality of it is something you have to have that light bulb, epiphany moment, but you have to build some chops through practice. This search combination gives you a lot of rich results.

Comment: This is a [particularly entertaining entry](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dependency-injection-is-evil.html) that tries to break through the hype-cycle driven cacophony of "DI OR DIE", which is funny because this is exactly how these things get hyped, adopted en masse by the unwashed masses, overexposed and then brought back to reality. Don't ever think that one approach is the answer to every problem.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Tony's a cool calculated guy, I've read an learnt a lot of stuff from him. Can't say i always agreed with his ideas but in this case he's right on the money! OOP encapsulation, information hiding, implementation hiding and polymorphism are themselves mechanism that lower coupling. Dependency injection creates a lot of support code to omnipresently remove depenency. IMO you should add that layer of indirection only when/where it is needed. If you forsee a sector of business logic that would benefit from proxied to another sector perhaps you should be implemening that semantically!